# Spotfire Table Visualization column width

Tags: width, visualization, spotfire

Is there a way to set Spotfire Table visualization column width either through Java or Python script. i can able to change the column width manually but whenever the value changes through property control it reset again. I need to set constant column width. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

good question! you can add an IronPython script (I don't believe it's possible to do this using Javascript unless you are some kind of wizard, or otherwise hate yourself :) to do this pretty simply.

I'll put the examples all in one code snippet, but obviously you would only want to do one of these loops at a time. the snippet expects a parameter called `viz` whose value is the TablePlot visualization you wish to modify.

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import TablePlot

v = viz.As[TablePlot]()

# increase all column widths by 10 pixels
for col in v.Columns:
    col.Width = col.Width + 10


# set all column widths to 100 pixels (the default value)
for col in v.Columns:
    col.Width = 100


# set the width of a specific column to 50 pixels
for col in v.Columns:
    if col.Name == "My Column":
        col.Width = 50
```

Comment: Thanks. This Works perfect

Comment: FYI looks like Spotfire has deprecated "Columns" in favor of "TableColumns"...so the above answer works if you replace `v.Columns` with `v.TableColumns` 
 
 [https://docs.tibco.com/pub/doc_remote/spotfire/7.5.0/doc/api/html/T_Spotfire_Dxp_Application_Visuals_TablePlot.htm]

Comment: good shout out @shwan! I accidentally un-upvoted you and now I can't re-upvote you -_- consider this an upvote :) ps, your link is malformatted and doesn't work. remove the ] at the end :)

Comment: @niko  So I can't seem to edit the link...no idea - SO bug.  Hey - so now that Columns are deprecated, how do I refer to a Table Column by name?  myTable.TableColumns["TheName"]  doesn't work...

Comment: right; it won't work because TableColumns is a collection containing a bunch of TableColumn objects. you'll need to iterate through it like `for tc in myTable.TableColumns: if tc.Name == "My Column": //do stuff`.

Comment: here's the doc link for the TableColumn object. should be basically the same thing as the Column object :) https://docs.tibco.com/pub/doc_remote/spotfire/7.5.0/doc/api/html/T_Spotfire_Dxp_Application_Visuals_TableColumn.htm

Answer (score 2):

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import TablePlot

# Tab is the (Visualization) parameter passed to the script specify the table to work on
dataTable= Tab.As[TablePlot]().Data.DataTableReference

# Get a handle to the Table plot
table = Tab.As[TablePlot]()

# Get the ColumnCollection for the Table plot
columns = table.TableColumns

# Size all of the columns 
for x in columns: 
    x.Width = 200
```

Comment: oi, should have hit refresh before I posted my answer. quick on the draw, @Mark P. :)